# Ao selecionar checkbox ele seleciona outros checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, checkbox

Não tenho conhecimento de JavaScript e estou utilizando framework Cakephp 3. Então meu problema é, eu tenho uma lista em que cada item da lista possui 2 checkbox, e quando eu selecionar o primeiro checkbox de um item ele selecionaria o outro automaticamente.

O que acontece é que quando eu seleciono o primeiro checkbox do item ele seleciona o segundo checkbox de toda a lista e não somente o segundo checkbox do item selecionado.

Esta é a minha view:

```
<form action="../vendas/" method="post">
<?= $this->Form->create("carrinho", ["class " => "form-add", "action" => "carrinho", "controller" => "Produtos-Vendas"]) ?>
<button type="submit" class="btn-success btn">Carrinho (<span id="additem"></span>)</button>
    <?php foreach ($produtos as $produto): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($produto->name) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($produto->cor) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($produto->tecido) ?></td>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->estoque) ?></td>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->preco) ?></td>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkTodos" name="check[]" class="checkbox checkTodos" value="<?php echo $produto['id'];?>">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkado" name="nome" value="<?php echo $produto['name'];?>">
            </td>
         </tr>   
         <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".checkTodos").click(function(){
    $('.checkado' && '#checkado').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Se desmarcar o primeiro é pra desmarcar o segundo tb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu seletor está errado. Deveria tratar apenas do checkbox checado (`$(this)`) e não todos.

Use `.next()` para selecionar o checkbox adjacente ao checkbox checado:

```
$(".checkTodos").click(function(){
   $(this).next().prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

> Ao fazer o laço, você está repetindo o `id="checkTodos"`, o que é
>   errado, pois um `id` não pode ser repetido na página. Ou você usa
>   `class="checkTodos"` ou remove se não for útil.

Comment: Obrigada essa foi a melhor solução para meu problema!

Comment: Obrigada a todos que me ajudaram, tentei solucionar com ideia de colocar no checkbox: id="id;?> Porém nao funcionou de primeira, pensei em ver outro jeito de gerar ID diferente para cada checkbox, mas antes testei a sugestao do .next() e funcionou com sucesso!

Muito obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Repare que vc está percorrendo uma lista de produtos, e para cada produto gera uma linha em uma tabela. Mas o seu `id` do checkbox é igual para todas as linhas dessa tabela. Tenta gerar um id para cada linha, talvez usando algum atributo do seu produto. tenta mudar e fala pra a gente o resultado.
EDIT: Tente algo do tipo:

```
<?php foreach ($produtos as $produto): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->id) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($produto->name) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($produto->cor) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($produto->tecido) ?></td>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->estoque) ?></td>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->preco) ?></td>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$produto->id;?>" name="check[]" class="checkbox checkTodos" value="<?php echo $produto['id'];?>">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkado" name="nome" value="<?php echo $produto['name'];?>">
        </td>
     </tr>   
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```